# Windows mapped drives too unreliable

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, smb

I manage a Windows 10 Pro system setup as a basic file server for multiple users.  Every user has their own dedicated Windows user and credentials.  Every client workstation has a `net map` script with pre-keyed credentials and runs at startup.

This setup *should* be reliable to but it seems a number of workstations continue to have problems.  Sometimes they certain drives just drop for discernible reason and are stubbornly disconnected after a reboot; at the same time, other workstations continue to have access that same shares without issue.

Other times, the drives are all X'd out, but function normally once navigated to (this confuses the users who don't even attempt to open them).

I've tried experimenting with giving some workstations a UNC shortcut with credentials saved as `WORKGROUP\username` to force persistence.  It works for a short while and then credentials are forgotten again.

This is endlessly frustrating and a constant game of a authentication whack-a-mole.

Is the an actual **reliable** way of setting up persistent network shortcuts on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

> I manage a Windows 10 Pro system setup as a basic file server for multiple users.

Windows 10 Pro is not designed to be a server operating system. Sure, you can set up file sharing, printing, but you will very quickly hit licensing limits. For example, Windows 10 Pro will allow only 20 concurrent share connections.

Use Windows Server 2019, or a Linux-based NAS with Samba for file sharing. (A dedicated fileserver such as a QNAP offers Active Directory service with a point'n'click interface.)

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  It's a small network and not exceeding concurrent connections, they don't need Windows server edition.  I don't see any reason that just using standard file sharing should be so unreliable.

Comment: Like I said, "_Windows 10 Pro is not designed to be a server operating system_"

Comment: This is an awful non-answer, microsoft has purpose designed windows to force you to maintain a separate dedicated windows server computer. It's complete B.S. This question deserves a real answer. If a raspberry pi can host samba shares reliably then any windows PC can. Windows 98 used to be share files reliably 24/7.

Comment: @Shodan please feel free to write your own answer. Don't shoot the messenger though - I didn't decide on licensing terms for Windows products, nor do I have any control over the reliability or otherwise of sharing from W10Pro. I've already suggested using a Samba solution

Comment: I assure you, I'm not shooting the messenger, I'm shooting the message, this is microsoft's message saying "on windows you better use windows server, or else it would be a shame if your stuff would break !"  Using samba doesn't help, it's the client breaking not the server.

Comment: I found these links that might help with this annoying issue, created on purpose by microsoft
https://github.com/yashielsookdeo/Auto-Reconnect-Mapped-Network-Drives
https://github.com/nickrod518/MapDrivesUtility
https://github.com/peterhorsley/mapdrive